# Encrypt each user's home folder individually with ZFS

Tags: login, encryption, users, zfs, pam

Scenario is that I have a pile of computers (with Ubuntu 20.04), each of which can have multiple users. Each user's account has to be encrypted individually.

As ecryptfs is no longer recommended, I took the following articles with ZFS based approaches as inspiration:

1. https://medium.com/@steinarlbergmyrvang/ubuntu-20-04-with-encrypted-home-f5ce490333cc
2. https://talldanestale.dk/2020/04/06/zfs-and-homedir-encryption/

I chose the "experimental" ZFS support during Ubuntu installation and wrote this script for creating a new user:

```bsh
username=foo
password=barbarbar

useradd "$username"
echo "$username":"$password" | chpasswd
zfs create \
  -o encryption=aes-256-gcm \
  -o keyformat=passphrase \
  -o keylocation=prompt \
  rpool/USERDATA/"$username"_encrypt \
  -o mountpoint=/home/"$username" \
  -o canmount=noauto
sudo chown "$username":"$username" /home/"$username"
```

When I omit `canmount=noauto`, then at bootup I have to enter all encryption passwords for all users created in this way. However, with `canmount=noauto`, I'm not prompted at all and login fails at the visual login screen. Logging in via terminal works, but the user's home folder still has to be unlocked.

I also tried to follow the steps 2-4 in the [second article](https://talldanestale.dk/2020/04/06/zfs-and-homedir-encryption/) to make an unlock script work that uses PAM, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

The second article you refer works superbly!

https://talldanestale.dk/2020/04/06/zfs-and-homedir-encryption/

I have just completed the implementation (with minor adjustments to suite local specifics)
Strongly recommended for the detailed instructions - just read carefully and you'll learn a lot of cool stuff.

Thanks for the pointers.